# Is it possible to delete Google Other Contacts via Apps Script?

Tags: google-people-api

**Scenario**

I'm a Google Workspace for Education admin. Every year we rename students' group names, but not their email addresses (ie '1st class' chimps@mydomain.edu becomes '2nd class' chimps@mydomain.edu)

when teachers search for groups (in Gmail, Classroom, etc.), autocompletion shows both the old and the new name: this is confusing, although groups and members are ok

this happens because on every first interaction with the group, user's Contacts app automatically save it in Other contacts; at new year's change, a new Other contact is added (not updating the previous one)

**Long solution**

Every teacher open Contacts > Other contacts and manually deletes the 'old groups', every new year

**What I would**

on new year beginning, a script that searches for Other contacts and deletes every students group if found (both a script that perform this on every user with domain-wide authority delegation to service account, or a web app that every teachers runs as himself would be ok); so no more old autocompletion, and new ones recreated at next interaction

I'm able to write down the script by myself, but I can't solve the followings

**The problem**

People API methods don't seem to support this in any way

- People.People.deleteContacts only works on Contacts, but not on Other Contacts
- People.OtherContacts methods seem to be readonly
- tried to override this using People.OtherContacts.copyOtherContactToMyContactsGroup, and then deleting the contact - not working, the method creates a copy of the Other Contact, it seems not to be moving it from Other Contacts to Contacts

but if I try this last thing from Contacts web app, I can add the Other Contact to Contacts, and this operation moves (not copies) the contact!

so:

1. am I missing anything that could do what I need via Apps script?
2. is there a way to replicate this last behavior (moving from Other contacts to Contacts, instead of creating a copy) in Apps script?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation, you are only able to [Read, Copy, and Search "Other contacts"](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/other-contacts).

You can create a [Feature Request on Google's Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) to ask for the contact to be editable.

Comment: ok, feature request created. thank you

Comment: at last, I didn't open a new feature request, starred instead an existing identical one. if anybody is looking for something similar to get introduced in People API, you could star the request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199768096